# Syslog-ng multiple filters

Tags: logging, syslog-ng, splunk, checkpoint

I am fairly new to syslog-ng and I have the following issue.

I have a Checkpoint firewall that sends the logs to a Splunk server. Due to the huge amount of data sent by the firewall, I tried to filter out the unwanted logs. As this was not possible on either the firewall or Splunk, I now send the firewall logs to a syslog-ng server which filters out the unwanted messages and forwards the rest of the logs to Splunk via Splunk-forwarder.

The log definition on the Syslog-ng server looks like this:

```
log {
    source { network(transport(tcp)  port(12001) flags(no-parse)); };<br>
    parser { checkpoint-parser(); };
    filter { not match("Application_Allow_all", value("MESSAGE")); };
    destination { file("/var/log/syslog-ng/checkpoint.txt"); };
};
```

80% of the firewall logs contain **"Application_Allow_all"**, which we do not need on the Splunk server. So far so good, the filter works.

Now to the problem. I need to have on the Splunk server the firewall logs containing "Webserver access". But the firewall log entries containing **"Webserver access"** also contain **"Application_Allow_all"**.

I don't know how to combine two filters, and what I've found on the internet so far doesn't work.

I have tried the following:

```
filter { match("Webserver access", value("MESSAGE")); };
filter { not match("Application_Allow_all", value("MESSAGE")); };
```

With these filters, I now only get the logs containing "Webserver access" and nothing else.
The second filter seem to be ignored.

This is how the log entry looks on the Splunk server:

```
"rule_action=Accept | rule_name=Webserver access | rule_name=Application_Allow_all"
```

What I want to achieve is to have the logs containing "Webserver Access" forwarded by syslog-ng to the Splunk server, while all other logs containing "Application_Allow_all" are discarded.

Any ideas welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be mistaken, but if I understand correctly, then you are looking for something like this:

```
     filter { match("Webserver access", value("MESSAGE")) or (not match("Application_Allow_all", value("MESSAGE"));  };
```

For details and examples, see [combining syslog-ng filters](https://axoflow.com/docs/axosyslog-core/chapter-routing-filters/filters/filters-boolean/).

Also, starting with version 4.2, [syslog-ng can send logs directly to Splunk](https://axoflow.com/docs/axosyslog-core/chapter-destinations/syslog-ng-with-splunk/), so you don't have to use the universal forwarder, and can do the filtering and sending with syslog-ng.

(the link points to the documentation of Axosyslog, which is a cloud-ready syslog-ng distribution maintained by the original creator of syslog-ng)

Answer (score 1):

Filtering can be done by Splunk.  Add the following to a props.conf file:

```
[mysourcetype]
TRANSFORMS-filter_appl_allow_all = rm_appl_allow_all
```

Then add this to the transforms.conf file in the same app

```
[rm_appl_allow_all]
REGEX = Application_Allow_All
DEST_KEY = queue
FORMAT = nullQueue
```

The transform discards any event that matches the specified regular expression (REGEX key).  The props setting invokes the transform.  The props.conf stanza name ("mysourcetype" above) must match the sourcetype name specified by the sending system.